# Selenium WebDriver doesn't click on a button in Google Emulator

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing automation using Google Emulator

```
    Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

When I try to click on a button on the mobile screen,, it does nothing, no error message as well, the test is pass.

```
    WebElement close = webDriver.findElement(By.id("closeIFrame"));
    close.click();
```

Any thoughts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try introducing a wait between those lines.

```
WebElement close = webDriver.findElement(By.id("closeIFrame"));
wait for a short while.
close.click();
```

The reason for this is occasionally, your code is too fast for the web page to catch up with.

**OR** try "hover" over this button and then "click",

**OR** use a chain action, here, http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains